# Empirical evidence of IE6/7/8 browser resolutions

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

These days, web sites need to be designed for a variety of different screen resolutions.  When designing for a desktop 3-column layout, typically we can assume at least **1024 x 768**, but we can also add features for higher resolutions because they are becoming increasing common.  (W3Cschools reports over [90% of visitors with higher screen resolutions](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp), and over [25% with screen resolutions of 1366x768](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp)).

However, if I'm designing a website where I also want to support older, Windows-XP browsers (the unholy trinity: IE-6,7, and 8), I also need to make certain assumptions about older screen resolution in the 800x600 to 1024x768 range.  Since none of these browsers support CSS3 `media` query, I'm left with the option of using some heavy Javascript to emulate media queries, or just assuming that these old browsers are typically in a certain resolution range and designing accordingly.

Intuitively, since IE-6, 7 and 8 users are most likely running Windows XP, (which reigned from about 2001 to ~2007-9 ), I would assume that IE-6, 7 and 8 users probably more typically have older machines with 1024x768 being a safe assumption.

Is there any empirical data that confirms what I assume here?  I can find many browser statistics and screen resolution statistics via a simple Google search, but I can't find any statistics that break down screen resolution by browser.  If, for example, I could get some evidence that let's say 70% of IE-7 users have a 1024x768 screen resolution, I would consider my assumption valid.

So, is there any evidence to backup my assumption here?

Comment: I used to have a 1920 x 1080 Monitor in 2006 on Windows XP, and I wasn't the only one... not sure it's safe to assume 1024 x 768 across the board here. The average resolution might be even higher than today because of the lower number of mobile / tablet devices in the 2000's.

Comment: Every site I know of has now stopped officially supporting IE6 and IE7. If they support them at all, it's a case of "it's just about usable" rather than making an effort to look good. Yes, IE8 is still relevant, but even then what's wrong with just using a polyfill like [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)? It's really not as heavy as you think.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php
800x600 is virtualy extinct.